# likert plot showing percentage values

Tags: r, plot, percentage

Below, I have R code that plots a likert plot.

```
set.seed(1234)
library(e1071)
probs <- cbind(c(.4,.2/3,.2/3,.2/3,.4),c(.1/4,.1/4,.9,.1/4,.1/4),c(.2,.2,.2,.2,.2))
my.n <- 100
my.len <- ncol(probs)*my.n
raw <- matrix(NA,nrow=my.len,ncol=2)
raw <- NULL
for(i in 1:ncol(probs)){
  raw <- rbind(raw, cbind(i,rdiscrete(my.n,probs=probs[,i],values=1:5)))
}

r <- data.frame( cbind(
  as.numeric( row.names( tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], mean) ) ),
  tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], mean),
  tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], mean) + sqrt( tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], var)/tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], length) ) * qnorm(1-.05/2,0,1),
  tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], mean) - sqrt( tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], var)/tapply(raw[,2], raw[,1], length) ) * qnorm(1-.05/2,0,1)
))
names(r) <- c("group","mean","ll","ul")

gbar <- tapply(raw[,2], list(raw[,2], raw[,1]), length)

sgbar <- data.frame( cbind(c(1:max(unique(raw[,1]))),t(gbar)) )

sgbar.likert<- sgbar[,2:6]



require(grid)
require(lattice)
require(latticeExtra)
require(HH)
sgbar.likert<- sgbar[,2:6]


yLabels = c(expression(a[1*x]),expression(b[2*x]),expression(c[3*x]))

likert(sgbar.likert,
       scales = list(y = list(labels = yLabels)),
       xlab="Percentage",
       main="Example Diverging Stacked Bar Chart for Likert Scale",
       BrewerPaletteName="Blues",
       sub="Likert Scale")
```

That looks like below. However, I want to show percentage value of each category as shown in the below picture.

[image]

I have tried this:

```
likert(sgbar.likert,
       scales = list(y = list(labels = yLabels)),
       xlab="Percentage",
       main="Example Diverging Stacked Bar Chart for Likert Scale",
       BrewerPaletteName="Blues",
       plot.percent.low=TRUE, # added this one
       plot.percent.high=TRUE, # added this one, too
       sub="Likert Scale")
```

But, it does not have any affect and does not make any differences.

So, how to show percentage values for each category?

Comment: Where does the function `rdiscrete` come from ?

Comment: @rafa.pereira: package `e1071`, it's loaded on the second line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't any parameter to achieve that, so you need to define a custom panel function, in this way :

```
### just reproduce your input
library(HH)
sgbar.likert <- data.frame(X1 = c(34L, 7L, 13L),X2 = c(1L, 4L, 13L),
                           X3 = c(7L, 84L, 24L), X4 = c(7L, 2L, 27L), X5 = c(51L, 3L, 23L))
yLabels = c(expression(a[1*x]),expression(b[2*x]),expression(c[3*x]))
### 

# store the original col names used in custom panel function
origNames <- colnames(sgbar.likert)

# define a custom panel function
myPanelFunc <- function(...){
  panel.likert(...)
  vals <- list(...)
  DF <- data.frame(x=vals$x, y=vals$y, groups=vals$groups)

  ### some convoluted calculations here...
  grps <- as.character(DF$groups)
  for(i in 1:length(origNames)){
    grps <- sub(paste0('^',origNames[i]),i,grps)
  }

  DF <- DF[order(DF$y,grps),]

  DF$correctX <- ave(DF$x,DF$y,FUN=function(x){
    x[x < 0] <- rev(cumsum(rev(x[x < 0]))) - x[x < 0]/2
    x[x > 0] <- cumsum(x[x > 0]) - x[x > 0]/2
    return(x)
  })

  subs <- sub(' Positive$','',DF$groups)
  collapse <- subs[-1] == subs[-length(subs)] & DF$y[-1] == DF$y[-length(DF$y)]
  DF$abs <- abs(DF$x)
  DF$abs[c(collapse,FALSE)] <- DF$abs[c(collapse,FALSE)] + DF$abs[c(FALSE,collapse)]
  DF$correctX[c(collapse,FALSE)] <- 0
  DF <- DF[c(TRUE,!collapse),]

  DF$perc <- ave(DF$abs,DF$y,FUN=function(x){x/sum(x) * 100})
  ###

  panel.text(x=DF$correctX, y=DF$y, label=paste0(DF$perc,'%'), cex=0.7)
}

# plot passing our custom panel function
likert(sgbar.likert,
       scales = list(y = list(labels = yLabels)),
       xlab="Percentage",
       main="Example Diverging Stacked Bar Chart for Likert Scale",
       BrewerPaletteName="Blues",
       panel=myPanelFunc,
       sub="Likert Scale")
```

[image]

The code is pretty convoluted, but the key is that panel function receives, (in the ellipsis `...` parameter), an x,y pair of coordinates for each bar and group factor for each of them (groups are the columns of the original likert input). The default panel function is `panel.likert`; so, after calling that, we can add our changes to the plotted panel (in this case the labels according to the bars coordinates).

Seems easy, but there are two problems :

1. groups are redefined when they are even, so the central column, in this case `"X3"` it's split in two groups: `"X3"` and `"X3 Positive"`.
2. plotted bars are "stacked", so to correctly compute the centers of them (in order to put a label) you need to calculate the cumulated sum of the coordinates, using the original column names ordering.

The above code does all those calculations, hopefully in a quite generic manner (read: you can change the input and it should work...).

Comment: that is impressive! Thanks!

Comment: In some cases you get data labels directly on top of others. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55825651

Comment: How can you keep the percentages to two decimal places? Using the code provided, I get numbers displaying well beyond significant figures.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm so close to making it work. Currently it works, but two of my categories get reversed. I have four categories (2 on each side of the 0 axis). The two to the right of zero are correct, but the two to the left of zero are not correctly placed in the middle of the bar segment and the order of them is reversed. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: I actually figured out my problem above, but the only remaining problem I have is if one of the factor levels has zero responses the zero always goes to the middle of the chart, when ideally it'd be excluded. Anyone know how to solve that?